# React Native Maps LocalTile with fallback to native map provider tiles

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps, apple-maps

I'm using react native maps with the `<LocalTile />` component to render custom maps in a react-native app.

This is all good and it's working but the tiles I'm using just cover a limited area and what I'm wondering is; is there a way to make **react-native-maps** fallback to use the native provider tiles when tiles defined with `pathTemplate` are not available? This seems only to be an issue on iOS because Android renders the google maps tiles behind the local tiles - this is the behaviour I'd like for iOS with apple maps as well.

Essentially I want to be able to render the custom map tiles that I have, and then have it fallback to the standard map for everything else.

```
const pathTemplate = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/map-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`;
......
<MapView>
  <LocalTile pathTemplate={pathTemplate} tileSize={256} />
</MapView>
```

Currently on iOS it just renders empty space with labels where the local tile set is not covered.

[edge of local map tiles region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dANtL.png)